# Android Studio - save all settings to account?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-2.3

I am using Android Studio while logged in with my Google account and I think there was an option to automatically save all settings of the IDE to your Google Account, so when you use it from another computer, everything would be imported. Is that even possible? How can I do it?

P.S. I mean, its not like we are 2017 or something.

Comment: It is possible on IntelliJ but on Android Studio, which is based on that, I was never been able to find out _how_.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure, whether it is possible or NOT. Just an alternate, you can export Android studio settings and import whenever you need it.

**Export Settings**

```
File -> Export Settings -> A popup will be opened -> Select options (All selected by default) -> OK
```

**Import Settings**

```
File -> Import Settings
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do that via git.

Create a repository on Gitlab or Github, then in Android Studio go to "File-> Settings Repository..." and add the repo URL there.

Comment: Kudos! It works